# How to get the currency pipe to work with only the country code?

Tags: angular, pipe, nativescript

I'm writing an application with NativeScript and Angular.
I have some output that I want to use the currency pipe for. However, I do not have a currency code. I only have a locale/country code. How can I get the pipe to work in my situation?

```
 {{ totalPerGuest | currency:null:null:null:selectedLocale }}
```

Comment: as far as I see it from the documentation, this should not be possible. `{{ value_expression | currency [ : currencyCode [ : display [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] ] ] }}` means that always the next parameter is optional if you provide the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    <!--output '$0.26'-->
    <p>A: {{a | currency}}</p>

    <!--output 'CA$0.26'-->
    <p>A: {{a | currency:'CAD'}}</p>

    <!--output 'CAD0.26'-->
    <p>A: {{a | currency:'CAD':'code'}}</p>

    <!--output 'CA$0,001.35'-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol':'4.2-2'}}</p>

    <!--output '$0,001.35'-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol-narrow':'4.2-2'}}</p>

    <!--output '0 001,35 CA$'-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol':'4.2-2':'fr'}}</p>

    <!--output 'CLP1' because CLP has no cents-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CLP'}}</p>
  </div>
```